# HTML Error: infdig error

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an HTML error:

"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22results%20%7C%20filter%3Asearch%20%7C%20filter%3A%20greaterThan('size'%2C%203000)%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B%7B%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%5C%22mu21p01sa%5C%22%2C%5C%22location%5C%22%3A%5C%22mu%5C%22%2C%5C%22status%5C%22%3A%5C%22prod%5C%22%2C%5C%22cluster_type%5C%22%3A%5C%22siri%5C%22%2C%5C%22size%5C%22%3A%5C%223551%5C%22%2C%5C%22dri%5C%22%3A%5C%22N%2FA%5C%22%2C%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%5C%226P5%5C%22%2C%5C%22rolling%20restart%20phase%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22start%5C%22%3A%5C%222013-07-07%5C%22%2C%5C%22end%5C%22%3A%5C%222013-08-07%5C%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%5C%22nk31p01sa%5C%22%2C%5C%22location%5C%22%3A%5C%22nk%5C%22%2C%5C%22status%5C%22%3A%5C%22dev%5C%22%2C%5C%22cluster_type%5C%22%3A%5C%22speech%5C%22%2C%5C%22size%5C%22%3A%5C%223941%5C%22%2C%5C%22dri%5C%22%3A%5C%22RL%5C%22%2C%5C%22version%5C%22%3A%5C%226N5%5C%22%2C%5C%22rolling%20restart%20phase%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22start%5C%22%3A%5C%222013-07-07%5C%22%2C%"[…] angular.min.js:92

That links me to this:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=undefined

I am in a gigantic HTML file and looking for mismatching tags could take a really long time. Has anyone seen this error before / have suggestions how to tackle this error?

Thanks!

---

Update: I think I may have found the error:

Why does 1 work but not 2?

```
         1. <div ng-show="filteredResults = (results | filter:search)" class="result">
              <h4> <center>PODs over 3000 Nodes:</center></h4>
            </div>

        2. <div ng-show="filteredResults = (results | filter:search | filter:greaterThan('size', 3000))" class="result">
              <h4> <center>PODs over 3000 Nodes:</center></h4>
            </div>



         AngularJS GreaterThan:

         $scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val){
          return function(item){
            if (item[prop] > val) 
              return true;
            else  
              return false;
          }
        }
```

---

Does anyone know how to filter by multiple criteria on AngularJS and feed the result into ng-show? 
                
                   PODs over 3000 Nodes:

In this code, I want to display the words: PODS over 3000 Nodes if and only if there are results left from filtered through search and filtered through greaterThan function in. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is off when variable assignment used with ng-show. Try this way instead:-

Just test the length of the result:-

```
<div ng-show="(results | filter:search | filter:greaterThan('size', 3000)).length" class="result">
    <h4> <center>PODs over 3000 Nodes:</center></h4>
</div>
```

and also:-

```
$scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val){
   return function(item){
         return (item[prop] > val) 
    }
  }
```

**[Plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KHabCs?p=preview)**

Note that this could be a really expensive operation especially if the number of items in the results are large, the filtering can be done at once traversing through the list using a custom filter itself.